# MAUI - entry converter with two values

Tags: xaml, binding, maui, converters

I have model with two properties:

- UInt32 Quantity (the number of decimal places depends on the unit)
- UnitType Unit

I would like to create converter for Entry which can convert data from/to decimal place according to Unit.

ConverterParameter is not bindable property. The Unit property is not static.

I tried to create Converter with "BindableProperty" and create this Converter within Resources.

```
        <converters:QuantityToUserTextConverter
            x:Key="QuantityToUserTextConverter"
            Unit="{Binding Product.Unit}">
        </converters:QuantityToUserTextConverter>
```

```
    public class QuantityToUserTextConverter : BaseConverter<UInt32, String?>
    {
        public static readonly BindableProperty UnitProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(Unit),
                                                                                       returnType: typeof(UnitTypes),
                                                                                       declaringType: typeof(QuantityToUserTextConverter),
                                                                                       defaultValue: null);

        public UnitTypes? Unit
        {
            get => (UnitTypes?)GetValue(UnitProperty);
            set => SetValue(UnitProperty, value);
        }
```

However, Unit property inside the QuantityToUserTextConverter is still set or equal with default.

Of course Product.Unit is correct and it is working property with other binding. (For example: Text={Binding Product.Unit} in Label)

Any idea why Binding in QuantityToUserTextConverter does not work?
Any idea how to use a converter for two values?

Thank you very much

Comment: MultiValueConvertor.

Comment: Hello, Your answer is again very helpful for me. The problem is solved. Thank you very much. My respect...